# opa 1.01 : node.js -> Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb'

Tags: node.js, opa

I've tried to compile my opa project with the new release 1.0.1. I'm now using :

```
node myApp.js
```

to run the server. I get the following error :

```
module.js:337
    throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'");
Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb'
```

Do I need to install a node.js module or something to use mongodb ? My mongodb used to work pretty well with the old native backend.

I've also tried to compile my app with the native backend, and I get that message :

```
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
MailMLRuntime referenced from /usr/lib/opa/stdlib/stdlib.qmlflat/stdlib.web.mail.smtp.client.opx/_build/cstdli
_2eweb_2email_2esmtp_2eclient.cmxa(Bsl_init_stdlib_2eweb_2email_2esmtp_2eclient)
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Also for checking you can use node REPL, type 'node' and then require('mongodb') to see if its finding the module.

Answer (score 2):

when you launch the compiled node app with `node myapp.js`, it will look for the node modules in your NODE_PATH.

However, if you launch it with `./myapp.js`, it will look at the Opa installation folder first, so that you don't have to install node dependencies yourself :)

Comment: I've already tried this solution, but I get the error : "Killed"

Comment: Where is this "Killed" error ? in the Terminal ? Which OS are you on ?

Comment: I'm working on an ubuntu 11.04. The console says : # ./myApp.js \n Killed \n #

Comment: It seems that opa use too much memory. I'm using a virtual server with only 512 mb of ram :(

Comment: Ok, cool. We are working on a fix for the native mail lib problem ;)